# React Native on custom platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Firstly, I'm working on a custom platform built on Node.js with hooks into an OpenGL rendering layer (for the UI) - there's no browser and therefore no DOM.

What I'd like to do is leverage Redux and React Native but obviously React Native doesn't support my custom platform. I've seen that people have forked the repo to turn React components into native components like iOS desktop and Windows desktop but I have no idea what steps would be involved in doing so.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few resources for this.

Kureev Alexey has put out a nice series of articles on how the bridge is build for iOS: https://medium.com/@kureevalexey/how-to-create-you-own-native-bridge-93a8d4a40bd2#.jeuohrrdp

I gave a talk at React Next 2016 on the topic of building native bridges, the slides are available here: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=3aa585633a83d44a&page=view&resid=3AA585633A83D44A!4396&parId=3AA585633A83D44A!120&app=PowerPoint

If you have specific questions, there is a fairly active group on the Reactiflux Discord in the #react-native-platforms channel. You can sign up at http://reactiflux.com

Comment: Eric, that OneDrive link says "This item might not exist or is no longer available" - can you check the permissions?